# how to terminate TLS mqtt to TCP with Kubernetes ingress-nginx controller. ERROR: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, emqx

I feel like I am close but I am not sure if I am just terminating wrong with the ingress controller and what I am trying is not possible. Or, the certificate is in the way and I need to do something to alleviate the issue.

Another idea I see is using a HAPROXY LB in front of the ingress-nginx controller.

First, I am using the ingress Nginx tcp/udp controller for Kubernetes described here with an Letsencrypt RA CA

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

This allows me through my `HELM` installation to create a tcp config and mapping.

```
 helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --create-namespace --namespace $NAMESPACE --set controller.service.annotations.service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path=/healthz,controller.service.annotations.service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-dns-label-name=$DNS_LABEL --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP=$STATIC_IP --set tcp.18083=$NAMESPACE/emqx-ee:18083,tcp.8883=$NAMESPACE/emqx-ee:8883
```

That does allow for an `mqtts://` ssl connection to go through all the way to the `8883` backend pod. The issue is when I want to terminate at the loadbalancer and send the resulting incoming traffic to terminate the TLS and go to the TCP 1883 port.

To try this I change the port tcp definition

from this:

`'8883': ingress-emqx/emqx-ee:8883`

to this:

`'8883': ingress-emqx/emqx-ee:1883`

When I connect the client `mqttx` to 8883 CA I get the resulting error:

`Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established`

What exactly does the termination for ingress-nginx? Is it only the ingress instruction rule or is it the controller TCP Proxy Protocol?

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/tls-termination/

Is the only way to terminate is to utilize the ingress instruction/rewrite rule? If so, I think this is where the controller won't work because the route ingress rule only works with http and won't act upon mqtt layer-7 protocol.

Is there a way for the ingress to align with the ingress-controller service? I'm not sure it even matters to the previous issue. I simply want to take the incoming 8883 port and switch it to the resulting 1883 port and IP.

Comment: I figured out how to do this through Hyproxy. That works perfectly!!!

Comment: hyproxy? did you mean haproxy? Can you give more info?